# C# enum typo correction

Tags: c#, enums

I am sure everyone made a typo somewhere during the development and realized it after it is released. Well, I am experiencing the same issue except this problem live in the Enum options.

I have a enum definition like below in C#

```
    public enum SlideShowZoomEffect
    {
        NoEffect,
        ZoomIn,
        ZoonOut
    }
```

Recently, after release of the product, we realize that there's a typo for ZoonOut (it should be ZoomOut). We want to change this but it is save into database as a string (so it is saved as ZoonOut) and program will reconstruct the enum by calling enum.parse(...) which allow us to use it in our program as an enum.

The problem here is that once we changed the ZoonOut to ZoomOut, is there any ways I can have backward compatible so that both (string)ZoonOut and (string)ZoomOut will be parsed as (enum)ZoomOut?

Any suggestion will be great!

Thank you

---

**UPDATE (Solution to this issue):**

With answer accepted below, here's my testing code to show the effect on this accepted solution for future reference purposes. Thank you all

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Testing input as (string)ZoomOut
        Console.WriteLine("Testing #1: Input String = 'ZoomOut'");
        TestCase("ZoomOut");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");


        //Testing input as (string)ZoonOut
        Console.WriteLine("Testing #2: Input String = 'ZoonOut'");
        TestCase("ZoonOut");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");


        //Additional testing to ensure the TestCase function is working, we should see something else detected here
        Console.WriteLine("Testing #3: Input String = 'ZoomIn'");
        TestCase("ZoomIn");
    }


    static void TestCase(string inputString)
    {
        SlideShowZoomEffect enumInput = (SlideShowZoomEffect)Enum.Parse(typeof(SlideShowZoomEffect), inputString);

        Console.WriteLine("enumInput.tostring() = " + enumInput.ToString());


        Console.WriteLine("\n===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoonOut:");
        switch (enumInput)
        {
            case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoonOut:
                Console.WriteLine("      ===> ZoomOut detected");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("      ===> Something else detected");
                break;
        }



        Console.WriteLine("\n===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoomOut:");
        switch (enumInput)
        {
            case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoomOut:
                Console.WriteLine("      ===> ZoomOut detected");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("      ===> Something else detected");
                break;
        }
    }


    public enum SlideShowZoomEffect
    {
        NoEffect,
        ZoomIn,
        ZoomOut,
        ZoonOut = ZoomOut
    }
}
```

Here's the output from console

```
Testing #1: Input String = 'ZoomOut'
enumInput.tostring() = ZoomOut

===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoonOut:
      ===> ZoomOut detected

===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoomOut:
      ===> ZoomOut detected




Testing #2: Input String = 'ZoonOut'
enumInput.tostring() = ZoomOut

===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoonOut:
      ===> ZoomOut detected

===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoomOut:
      ===> ZoomOut detected




Testing #3: Input String = 'ZoomIn'
enumInput.tostring() = ZoomIn

===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoonOut:
      ===> Something else detected

===> using case SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoomOut:
      ===> Something else detected
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What is the problem with the simple-minded approach: read a string, change 4th letter to ‘m’ if ‘n’, then `parse`? (Assuming you don’t go for a clean slate after all.)

Comment: You can either have `ZoomOut=ZoonOut` in the enum or (better approach) you can fix your code and your database.

Comment: Update the value in the database.

Comment: In the future, just as an FYI, you should be serializing enums to `int`s instead of strings. That would have avoided this issue altogether.

Comment: In the future, I recommend GhostDoc, saved me a few times. http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
  public enum SlideShowZoomEffect
    {
        NoEffect,
        ZoomIn,
        ZoomOut,
        ZoonOut = ZoomOut

    }
```

Edit: your safest bet would be to use @Bas' suggestion.

Comment: Actually I don't think it will, it should be `ZoomOut = ZoonOut`, otherwise you are redefining the numerical value of `ZoonOut` and breaking existing code.

Comment: There's a problem with this - if the enum is being serialized as strings rather than ints (in a public-facing API) then exposing multiple equivalent values does not help consumers that are doing mappings or comparisons. If that's not the case then there's really no reason not to just change it.

Comment: @Ron Beyer, since ZoonOut = ZoomOut and ZoomOut replaces the old ZoonOut, they both have the same value, which is the old value of ZoonOut.

Comment: @Ant P, the question was " so that both (string)ZoonOut and (string)ZoomOut will be parsed as (enum)ZoomOut?", my code does exactly that.

Comment: It does, but it's probably not actually as simple as the asker is assuming. If the enum values are exposed to consumers then there's a very real chance that a consumer is performing conditional logic based on the value of the enum. If that suddenly changes, just parsing the enum differently on the way *in* is only half of the story.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, it will only add confusion whenever someone wants to use this enum and gets these strange duplicate'ish values.

Comment: @Magnus, I agree with you on that.

Comment: @Magnus, definitely this will create tons of confusion. However, we just need that temporary so all older distributions of software can still communicate with server. Once all clients are updated with the latest patch, then we can make the server end to be more strict. For reference purposes, definitely don't do this band-aid approach!

Comment: @RonBeyer, thanks for pointing this out, I will go ahead and create a small testing project to test it out.

Comment: @Alioza, thank you for this band-aid solution. I think this is what we needed. Will test it in a small testing projects and get back to you with the result soon. Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 9):

Alternative answer for Alioza's approach:

```
update TableX set MyEnumField = 'ZoomOut' where MyEnumField = 'ZoonOut'
```

Run it when you patch your product ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We will definitely run that update SQL. However, the problem we're experiencing is that since the Enum definition has been distributed across multiple platforms including website, firmware as well as windows application, we want to ensure backward and forward compatibility for devices running older version of the firmware/software.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your best bet should be using attributes on enumeration values.

For example, you may implement an attribute `SynonymAttribute`:

```
public class SynonymAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    public SynonymAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, you should use the `SynonymAttribute` whenever you want to map a synonym to some existing enumeration value:

```
public enum SlideShowZoomEffect 
{
     NoEffect,
     ZoomIn,

     [Synonym("ZoonOut")]
     ZoomOut
}
```

Finally, you can implement some helper method like this to workaround your situation:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(string nameOrSynonym, out TEnum enumValue)where TEnum : struct
    {
        enumValue = default (TEnum);
        bool success = false;
        TEnum result;

        // First of all, this is the first attemp to parse the enum
        // value using regular Enum.TryParse. If it succeeds, it will mean
        // that passed enum value name is already in the enumeration. 
        if (!Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(nameOrSynonym, true, out result))
        {
            nameOrSynonym = nameOrSynonym.ToLowerInvariant();

            // If we need to look for a synonym of passed enumeration value
            // name, then we need reflection to look for static fields
            // in the given enumeration type. Enumeration values are just
            // static fields.

            // The SingleOrDefault part will look for fields with 
            // SynonymAttribute and it will extract the one with the
            // synonym which equals the passed enumeration value name!
            FieldInfo enumValueField = typeof (TEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetField)
                                                    .SingleOrDefault
                                                    (
                                                        field => field.GetCustomAttribute<SynonymAttribute>() != null 
                                                                && field.GetCustomAttribute<SynonymAttribute>().Name.ToLowerInvariant() == nameOrSynonym
                                                    );



            // If the synonym was found, then we get the field value
            // and we set it to the result enum value!
            if (enumValueField != null)
            {
                enumValue = (TEnum)enumValueField.GetValue(null);
                success = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            enumValue = result;
            success = true;
        }

        return success;
    }
}
```

Here's a sample usage of the `EnumHelper.TryParse` with synonym support:

```
    SlideShowZoomEffect enumValue;

    EnumHelper.TryParse<SlideShowZoomEffect>("ZoonOut", out enumValue);

    // This will output "ZoomOut"!
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", enumValue.ToString("f"));
```

Also, same sample in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LAhHU8)!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public enum SlideShowZoomEffect
{
    NoEffect = 1,
    ZoomIn = 2,
    ZoonOut = 3,
    ZoomOut = 3
}
```

I tried it in simple console program. It shows they are identical.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool result = (SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoonOut == SlideShowZoomEffect.ZoomOut); //True
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```